# change search result page to 1 column

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, search

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1

Where can i change the results section from the search results page to show only 1 column?

Now it shows search results with class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" and in the sidebar the layered nav (col-lg-3)

i do not need the sidebar... what and where would i need to change do i need to do it in an xml file or phtml file?

Thanks
Carlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/1column.phtml</template> 
    </action>
  </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying your catalogsearch.xml file located at `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout`
Try to find the following handles

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
```

and

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_index translate="label">
```

where you would find the following nodes

```
 <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

and

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

Change here for the desired layout
like

```
<template>page/1column.phtml</template>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: thanks although the previous answer worked for me, this still learned me new things